# Powershell Import-CSV and Foreach-Object, excluding with the CSV header

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the SAMAccountNames of one domain and compare them with their equals from another domain.

To get all users of dc1 I use:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase | Select-Object SamAccountName |
    Export-Csv -path $exports -encoding "unicode" -notype
```

and then I import the csv again and try to compare them for any differences

```
$readthat = Import-CSV $exports -Header SamAccountName | ForEach-Object {
  $user1 = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties $attributes
  $user2 = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Properties $attributes -Server $dc2

  $modified = @{}
  $attributes | Where-Object { $user1.$_ -ne $user2.$_ } | ForEach-Object {
    $modified[$_] = $user2.$_
  }
}
```

All that works great, except that it's also trying to find the SamAccountName which of course genereates an error because the SamAccountName = SamAccountName doesn't exit.

Any hints on how to avoid this or do you guys have a more elegant solution?

the .csv looks like this:

```
"SamAccountName"
"foo"
"bar"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `-Header SamAccountName` option on your `import-csv` should help immensely.  The `-Header` option is for when the CSV file you are importing doesn't have a header.  The `Export-CSV` cmdlet puts the header in there for you, so you don't have to.

Comment: must have missed that part when reading into the import/export function.
thanks